# Including Elasticsearch in Ember-CLI application

Tags: ember.js, elasticsearch, ember-cli

I am new to Ember and Node, and I would like to use Elasticsearch with Ember.

I'm using the npm elasticsearch package.

From what I gather, I should inject ES as a service, but I'm not sure where to include the ES initialization code and register the client with the Ember app.

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
});`
```

All I've got right now is `ember g service elasticsearch`

I appreciate the help for a noob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to use the elastic search client directly in your ember application (correct me if I am wrong). Unfortunately, you cannot use the node module directly within ember so you will need to architecture your application differently.

You have a few options:

**1)** Use a library like [Ember Data Adapter for elasticsearch](https://github.com/karmi/ember-data-elasticsearch) or [ember-data-elasticsearch-kit](https://github.com/roundscope/ember-data-elasticsearch-kit) in your ember application (which will run in the browser) to query elastic search. (I picked these since they were the first results in Google - they seem to be a bit out of date, but perhaps you can find something with more recent updates.)

**2)** Create an API endpoint with node (and perhaps something like [Express](http://expressjs.com/api.html)) and use the `elasticsearch` module and elastic search client to query elastic search on the server and return JSON which you can consume in your ember application. So, for instance:

```
    $.ajax({
       url: 'UrlOfMethodExposedByNode',
       type: 'GET',
       accepts: 'application/json',
       success: function(data) {
           // you can use the data here to set a value on a controller, etc
       },
       error: function() {
           // something went wrong while retrieving data from your API
       }
   });
```

More details will depend on the specifics of your application.

Comment: Thanks Oren.  Yes I saw those adapters and that they were out of date, so I shied away from them.  My intention was to do something like #2, but I was unsure how to set that up.

Comment: If you add some more specifics about how you are trying to use elasticsearch within your application I can try to provide more details about a possible implementation so it will be easier to fill in the gaps.

Comment: I am implementing an Instant Search in Ember.  I have external XML data that I would like to load into ES, which a user can then Instant Search through.  I would like there to be parameters which determine relevancy to the user which I can define in ES.

Comment: Also is there a downside to doing this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201036/add-node-module-to-ember-cli-app

Comment: No downside other than having another package bundled along with your app that will increase the total size of the page that has been downloaded when someone visits your app.