# emberjs, node and dependencies

Tags: node.js, ember.js, underscore.js

I declare dependencies in my app.js (ember) file, such as:

```
var _ = require('underscore');
```

Since my app.js file will be sent to the client and need to execute in a browser, how would this code be made available to the client?

Currently I'm using lineman to concatenate and uglify all my js files, and inside my vendors folder I did include underscore.min.js (all of this get bundled up into app.js) - yet my app isn't working.

Could someone kindly explain the process of adding npm packages to an ember app and the resulting requirements on the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Ember Browserify](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify) to use node packages in your ember app.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28219422/77074) for specific usage.

To install Ember Browserify:

```
npm install --save-dev ember-browserify
```

and utilize something from a package isntalled through NPM:

```
import Xyz from 'npm:xyzPackage';
```

Comment: This totally works! I recently did a proof of concept for a hebcal npm https://github.com/kalmanh/em-hebcal